# Get function value in Android

Tags: java, android, radio-group

**Question**: I am trying to take the index of the selected radio button and use that in the onClick function.

Example:

```
    btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
               if (getIndex(k) == 0) {
                      DO THIS
               }       
               if (getIndex(k) == 1) {
                      DO THAT
               }                
    });
```

I have the following code in my Android app:

```
    int POS; //global variable assigned right under MainActivity
    final RadioGroup rgTypeOfTrip = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTripType);
    Button btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(getIndex(POS1)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //DOESN'T WORK
        });

        rgTypeOfTrip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // Method 1
                int pos=rgTypeOfTrip.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                    getIndex(pos);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

public int getIndex(int POS1) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(POS1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // WORKS
    return POS1;
}
```

How can I achieve this line:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, CALL FUNCTION GETINDEX() to get value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To call the function to get the value of `k`?

Comment: Can you try rewording the question a little as it is unclear exactly what you are asking

Comment: @Chucky I think the question is in the `Toast`...

Comment: I reworded for better understand with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question is in the `Toast` such that it is: "CALL FUNCTION GETINDEX() to get value"

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(getIndex(int)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You pass in the integer that is returned though so you could just go with the following (under my assumptions of your code):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(int), Toast.LENGTH_S
```

Comment: I get this error after using the first method: `Syntax error on token "int", invalid ArgumentList`

Comment: I put int in only as a place holder. You will need to replace it with the value that you want to display.

Comment: I updated my code based on your response. Please let me know if it's correct.

Comment: Now it's forcing me to initialize it but then if it's initialized It doesn't keep the value for `k`

Comment: declare it as a global variable.

Comment: Maybe I declared it as FINAL... I removed it and let's see what it does now.

Comment: Same thing, the value is whatever I initialize it as :(